# How to find the type of a pair from iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, generic-programming

I am newbee here as well as in template programming. 
I have a dictionary (means, it could be either `std::map` or `std::vector<std::pair<type1, type2>>` or `std::set<std::pair<, >`> ...)
I wanted to write an algorithm, which act like standard library algorithms
using the iterators of the passed container.

Following is the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

// two different types
enum EnumA { one, two, three, four, five, six};
enum EnumB { one,      three, four,       six};

//                   TypeA TypeB
using map = std::map<EnumA, EnumB>;
           // or std::vector<std::pair<EnumA, EnumB>>
           // or std::set<std::pair<EnumA, EnumB>>
           // or std::array<std::pair<EnumA, EnumB>, 3>

const  map itemMap{       // the map
   {EnumA::one, EnumB::one}, 
   {EnumA::three, EnumB::three}, 
   {EnumA::six, EnumB::six}, 
};

template<typename Iterator, typename B>
/* type of KEY(first) of the map/container from the iterator???*/ AfromB(Iterator begin, Iterator end, B bObj)
{
   // static_assert(begin != end); // container should not be empty!
   using Type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
   using AType = decltype( /* how to find the type of KEY(first) of the map/container? */);
   using BType = decltype(/* how to find the type of VALUE(second) of the map/container? */);

   auto iter = std::find_if(begin, end, [bObj](const Type& entry) { return entry.second == bObj;});
   return iter != end ? iter->first: begin->first; // if not found return the first element match
}
// will do BfromA(Iterator begin, Iterator end, B bObj) similarly afterwards

int main()
{
   EnumA aEnum = AfromB(itemMap.cbegin(), itemMap.cend(), EnumB::six);  // I can use it like
}
```

There you can see in the code, I do not know how to find the type of 
key/ first and value/second of the pair in the dictionary. After googling,
I found I can find the type of key-value pair by

```
using Type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
```

but not for the individuals of that pair. Is it possible to find?
Im using C++11.

Sorry for the bad English. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `static_assert(begin != end);` cannot be compile time, you might use regular `assert` though.

Comment: Notice that `const` appears differently in resulting pair depending to your container.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the suggestion, I will consider it afterwards.

Comment: Why are you using `std::vector` or `std::set` of pairs, instead of [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or another container designed for this?

Comment: @DanielH Sorry, if I understood correctly, it has no `key-vale` pair system, rather hashes. I am a beginner, and thought of having simple `std::pair<key, value>`.  I know that `std::mapy<std::pair<const key, value>>`, that is why I inlcuded in the consideration

Comment: @LernerCpp Both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are associative containers and store the key and the value, not just hashes. An `unordered_map` *also* hashes the key, in order to speed up storage and lookup, but it stores it in full. In most cases, these data structures would be your best bet for associative containers; you'd usually only use an `std::vector<std::pair<T, U>>` when you aren't actually planning to look elements up by the first element of the pair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the maps value type:

```
using Type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
```

A maps value type is a [`std::pair<first_type,second_type>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) and to get a pairs first and second type you can use its `first_type` and `second_type`:

```
using key_type = typename Type::first_type;
using mapped_type = typename Type::second_type;
```

To use the `key_type` as return type I'd probably use a small helper:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct KeyAndMappedType {
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    using const_key_type = typename value_type::first_type;
    using key_type = typename std::remove_const<const_key_type>::type;
    using mapped_type = typename value_type::second_type;
};
```

and then

```
template <typename Iterator, typename B>
typename KeyAndMappedType<Iterator>::key_type AfromB(Iterator begin, Iterator end, B bObj) {
    ...
}
```

Note that a maps `key_type` is always `const`. As sometimes you need that type also as non-const, I decided that my `KeyAndMapType` should provide both (maybe naming should have been reversed, ie `key_type` as `const` and a `non_const_key_type`, but I'll leave it up to you to decide on the details).

Comment: Can you show the OP how they could make the return type `key_type`?

Comment: some `remove_const` might be required, depending of need.

Comment: That look intresting. I didn't know about it. Could you show me in the example code that? Escpecially the part, to set the return type. Here I tried: https://godbolt.org/z/yCANqh

Comment: @LernerCpp sry, dont really understand, what part you didnt know about? I already tried to show the example of using it as return type, if something is unclear, please ask

Comment: @LernerCpp return type deduction is only C++14, and a trailing return type is not necessary here

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The `using key_type = typename std::remove_const<key_type>::type;` should be maybe `using key_type = typename std::remove_const<const_key_type >::type;`.I think there is some typo somewhere in your struct. I have tried the code with your changes. But still not compiling: https://godbolt.org/z/-ikHpj

Comment: @LernerCpp the typo is in your code, here `auto iter = *std:...` you are derferencing the returned iterator via `*` so `iter` is actually not an iterator, but the element. Without the `*` it should be fine. I am planning to start a `NAA` campaign ("Not Always auto") :P, seriously, sometime `auto` can cause a type mismatch that would be obvious without `auto`...

Comment: @LernerCpp oh right and there was a typo in my struct, fixed that

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes,... that was my mistake. Sorry. Now it is working as expected... https://godbolt.org/z/bVCNq9. Thanks alot.